# UFT is not recognizing Web Objects appropriately

Tags: hp-uft

My hard drive crashed and I had to perform a clean install of Windows. I installed UFT version 11.5 and I having issue with UFT identifying Internet Explorer Dialogs as Web Objects. It seems to be related only to windows that were opened through a Modal Dialog Process. If I launch a new test, the object repository can recognize the browser correctly, it is only objects under a Modal Window that are not being identified as web objects. They are being identified as WinObject : Internet Explorer_Server.

This is working on all other workstations in my organization.

I have tried the following:
-Made sure that Web Add-In was enabled.
-Made sure that UFT was launched first berfore browser is loaded for TEST.
-Uninstalled and reinstalled UFT.
-Ran under admin account with full permissions.
-Made sure BHOManager Class is Enabled as Add-On within Internet Explorer
-Made sure BHOManager DLL were registered.
-Updated to the latest UFT patches.

Internet Explorer is version 8. As I stated before, it is working correctly on other machines. It is strange how it is only Modal Dialogs that are not identified properly.

Here is the mic config file:

```
[ie_hook]
name=ie_hooksU.dll
method=specific
explorer.exe=yes
iexplore.exe=yes
ie4.exe=yes
mshta.exe=yes
waol.exe=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there I needed to install Visual Basic add-on. Although it was not required for the application, it contained certain dependencies that needed to be installed in order for it to work. Thanks to iDeliver support for the solution www.ideliver-inc.com .